# Need to print data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array that I get dynamically from my server every day:

This is the array :

```
Array ( 
    [status] => success 
    [summary] => Array ( 
        [views] => 481 
        [clicks] => 251 
        [downloads] => 222 
    ) 
    [detailed] => Array ( 
        [2014-08-02] => Array ( 
            [views] => 59 
            [clicks] => 34 
            [downloads] => 27
        )
        [2014-08-03] => Array ( 
            [views] => 252 
            [clicks] => 135 
            [downloads] => 120 
        ) 
        [2014-08-04] => Array ( 
            [views] => 170 
            [clicks] => 82 
            [downloads] => 75 
        ) 
    ) 
    [countries] => Array ( 
        [PH] => 11 
    ) 
)
```

I want to print only the `[detailed]` array with his data but I don't know how to do it.

I used this :

```
foreach($responseData[detailed] as $child1) {
    foreach($child1 as $child) {
       echo $child ." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

But it prints all the data WITHOUT the date:

```
59 34 27 
252 135 120 
170 82 75
```

I want that it to be like this:

```
2014-08-02 - 59 34 27 
2014-08-03 - 252 135 120 
2014-08-04 - 170 82 75
```

Please remember that everyday I get a driftnet array data with a different dates.

thanks

Comment: The date is a key, not a value; have a play with `foreach($child1 as $key => $child) {`

Comment: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($responseData['detailed'] as $key => $child1) {
    echo $key, ' - ';
    foreach($child1 as $child) {
       echo $child ." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rather than having a loop inside a loop you can also use `implode`

```
   foreach($responseData['detailed'] as $key => $child1) {
    echo $key, ' - ';
    echo implode(" ", $child1);
    echo "\n";
}
```